# Fatal error: require_once():

Tags: php, pear, fatal-error, require-once

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: require_once(D:/xampp/htdocs/inc/head.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce1\index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'D:/xampp/htdocs/inc/head.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce1\index.php on line 3

I have the following code : located in `D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce1 Index.php`

```
<!--head-->
<?php $title="Gamer"?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. '/inc/head.php';?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. '/inc/menu.php';?>
<!--body of the page-->
<!--footer of the page-->
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. '/inc/footer.php';?>
`
```

This is the `head.php` which is located in `D:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce1\inc`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php print $title ?> </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Sorry i'm kinda new to php - where i should paste this code cause it doesn't do nothing

Comment: Actually you need to do either  `<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. 'ecommerce1/inc/head.php';?> and so on for others` OR `<?php require_once 'inc/head.php';?> and so on for others`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in your index.php.

```
<?php $title="Gamer"?>
<?php require_once 'inc/head.php';?>
<?php require_once 'inc/menu.php';?>
<!--body of the page-->
<!--footer of the page-->
<?php require_once 'inc/footer.php';?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: PLEASE ADD WHY YOU DID THAT. SOME REASONS WILL BE MORE GOOD.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you explicitly change the `DocumentRoot` setting in Apache's `httpd.conf`, the Document Root is by default in `D:/xampp/htdocs` .

So you need to call:

```
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. 'ecommerce1/inc/head.php';?>
```

instead of

```
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. '/inc/head.php';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to include files in php

**Method 1:** [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

```
<?php $title= "Gamer"; ?>
<?php include('inc/head.php');?>
<?php include('inc/menu.php');?>
<!--body of the page-->
<!--footer of the page-->
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

**Method 2:** [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

```
<?php $title= "Gamer"; ?>
<?php require_once('inc/head.php');?>
<?php require_once('inc/menu.php');?>
<!--body of the page-->
<!--footer of the page-->
<?php require_once('inc/footer.php');?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner you should know when to use `include()` and when to use `require()`.

In your case, use `include()` instead of `require_once()`.

The reason behind this is that if the `require_once()` fails to load a file, then the script execution would stop right there. If you use `include()` it would just throw an error and would continue execution.

**So, when to use `require_once()` over `include()`?**

Use `require_once()` when including PHP(or important server-side) scripts and `include()` when including template-like files.

Take a look at this example:

```
<?php include_once('inc/head.php');?>
<?php include_once('inc/menu.php');?>

<!--if including a script-->
<?php require_once('inc/footer.php');?>
```

*Note: It's good practice to use brackets and treat those functions like functions.*